# If $a_1=1, a_n=|\cot a_{n-1}|$, then what is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\text{median}\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, recurrence-relations, ergodic-theory, median

I made up the following sequence: $a_1=1, a_n=|\cot a_{n-1}|$.

> What is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\text{median}\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$ ?

**My thoughts**

Here is the graph of $a_n$ against $n$, for $1\le n \le 25$.

[image]

Using Excel, we have

$\text{median}\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{100}\}\approx 1.107$
$\text{median}\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{1000}\}\approx 1.172$
$\text{median}\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{10000}\}\approx 1.204$
$\text{median}\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{20000}\}\approx 1.201$

It seems that the median converges to something like $1.2$.

Here are the graphs of $y=|\cot x|$ and $y=x$.

[image]

We start at $(1, |\cot 1|)$, then go horizontally to the line $y=x$, then go vertically to the curve $y=|\cot x|$, then go horizontally to the line $y=x$, etc. Among the points that we meet on the curve $y=|\cot x|$, apparently (based on Excel) about half of them are below the line $y=1.2$.

Note: If we change $a_n$ from $1$ to any other non-zero integer, the median seems to converge to the same number, approximately $1.2$.

Comment: I've run a Matlab program with $n=10^7$ and $a_1=\pm5\pm5i$ and consistently find that the median is about 1.2, That said, even at that large number of terms, the result is different for every case tried. These calculations take of the order of 1.15 seconds,

Comment: [Possibly related:](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4781942/398708) Conjecture: If $a_1\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $a_n=\sec (a_{n-1})$ then the proportion of positive terms approaches $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a conditional result, providing a candidate for the value of the limit.

---

Let $x_1 = 1$ and $x_{n+1} = \cot x_n$. Since $\cot$ is an odd function, we have $|x_n| = a_n$ for all $n$. Based on some numerical experiments, we make the following ansatz:

> **Assumption.** The empirical probability measure $\mu_N = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \delta_{x_n}$ converges weakly to the centered Cauchy distribution  $\mu$ with shape parameter $\gamma > 0$, that is,
>
> $$ \mu_N(\mathrm{d}x) \to \mu(\mathrm{d}x) = \frac{\gamma}{\pi(x^2 + \gamma^2)} \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Under this assumption, for $x > 0$ we have

$$ \mathbf{P}_{X\sim \mu_N}(|X| \leq x) \to \mathbf{P}_{X\sim\mu}(|X| \leq x) = \frac{2}{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{\gamma}\right), $$

and then it can be proved that

\begin{align*}
[\text{median of $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$}]
&= [\text{median of $|X|$, where $X \sim \mu_N$}] \\
&\to [\text{median of $|X|$, where $X \sim \mu$}]
= \gamma.
\end{align*}

So it suffices to determine the value of $\gamma$. To this end, consider a random variable $X \sim \mu$. Then $\cot X$ has the same distribution as $X$. By comparing the PDF of $X$ and $\cot X$, we get

\begin{align*}
\frac{\gamma}{\pi(x^2 + \gamma^2)}
= \frac{1}{1+x^2} \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{\gamma}{\pi((\operatorname{arccot} x + k \pi)^2 + \gamma^2)}
= \frac{\coth \gamma}{\pi(x^2 + \coth^2 \gamma)}.
\end{align*}

Therefore $\gamma$ must satisfy $\gamma = \coth \gamma$. This equation has a unique positive solution with the value

$$ \gamma \approx 1.1996786402577338339, $$

which agrees with the numerical observation made by other users.

---

**Addendum.** Below is the probability histogram of first $10^4$ terms of $(x_n)$ and the graph of PDF of the limiting
Cauchy distribution $\mu$:

[image: Comparison]

**Caution.** Numerical simulation are not totally suited for probing the behavior of the median.

This is because the sequence $(x_n)$, hence $(a_n)$, is *very susceptible* to small numerical errors, which is significantly amplified when a term gets close to one of the poles of $\cot$. (This is essentially due to loss of significance.)

For instance, simulating $n \mapsto \text{median}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ using machine precision and $10000$-digit precision shows fairly different behavior even starting around $n = 20$:

[image: Comparison]

Comment: Very interesting! I just thought that, this is a deterministic sequence. Would it be possible to please share more details on theAssumption you made?

Comment: @Math-fun, There is no randomness at all. Rather, the sequence $(x_n)$ is expected to demonstrate an ergodic behavior, meaning that we expect $(x_n)$ to look like a snapshot of some random sequence with certain statistical pattern. As for the assumption, in a layman's term, it tells that "the histogram for $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N$ becomes stabilized as $N$ grows, and the limiting histogram actually comes from a well-known distribution".

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am happier now :-)

Comment: Do you have an idea how the Assumption of Cauchy convergence might be proven?

Comment: @BenjaminWang, Unfortunately, this type of problem (of establishing ergodicity of a specific sequence) is extremely difficult, if not impossible by contemporary math. Maybe it might possibly be able to prove the claim for a *generic* (i.e., almost every) initial condition $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}$, although this still sounds quite hard and I am not sure if I can manage to prove this...

Answer (score 1):

I've expanded my examination of this problem. I have run out the sequence to $n=10^7$ with $a_1=1$, as before. I attempted to find the median for each value of $n$ but it was too time consuming. I stopped the calculation at $n\approx 3.5\cdot10^6$ and then continued the calculation for the last 100,000 points. The results are shown in the two figures below. As you can see in the second figure, the results do not settle down to a constant value at all. It is my *opinion* that they never will.

[image: Median 1:3.6M]

[image: Median detail]

Comment: One thing to note is that numerical simulation of the sequence $(a_n)$, hence its median, is very susceptible to numerical errors.

Comment: @SangchulLee Point taken, so how does your 10,000 (!) digit precision look out at, say, $n=10^6$.

Comment: Loss of digit is so severe that the computation encountered division-by-zero error around $n\approx 1.4\times 10^4$. If this trend continues, I guess we would need about 1,000,000 digit precision to reach terms around $n=10^6$. This will certainly drain my RAM and take eternity to be done... :(

Comment: Interesting. I was able to compute $10^7 a_n$ in .5 secs (normal machine accuracy). But it took many many hours to compute $3\cdot10^6$ medians. By the way, do you know Prof. Rushan Ziatdinov  at Keimyung University, Daegu, South Korea?

Comment: No, unfortunately :(