# Conjecture: If $a_1\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $a_n=\sec (a_{n-1})$ then the proportion of positive terms approaches $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, recurrence-relations, ergodic-theory, conjectures

I made up the following family of sequences: $a_1\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $a_n=\sec (a_{n-1})$ for $n>1$.

> I conjecture that, for any $a_1\in\mathbb{Z}$, the proportion of positive terms approaches $\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}}$ as $n\to\infty$. Is my conjecture true?

**Evidence for my conjecture**

For $a_1=1$, here is the graph of $a_n$ against $n$ for $1\le n \le 25$.

[image]

Using Excel, it seems that, the proportion of positive terms approaches a limit as $n\to\infty$, and the limit is independent of the value of $a_1$.

I found that, for $a_1=1, 2, 3, \dots, 25$, among the first $10000$ terms, the average proportion of positive terms is $0.398940$, which is very close to $\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi}}\approx 0.398942$.

**Another look at the sequence**

Here are the graphs of $y=\sec x$ and $y=x$.

[image]

We start at $(1,\sec 1)$, then go horizontally to the line $y=x$, then go vertically to the curve $y=\sec x$, then go horizontally to the line $y=x$, etc. Among the points that we meet on the curve $y=\sec x$, about $0.39894$ of them are above the $x$-axis.

Comment: [Possibly related:](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4781295/398708) If $a_1=1, a_n=|\cot a_{n-1}|$, then what is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\text{median}\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$?

Comment: The function $f(x)=\sec x$ should have some invariant measure (in the sense of ergodic theory) associated to it, and presumably that measure assigns mass $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ to the set $(0,\infty)$. That should prove the claim for almost all starting values; I'm not sure what additional fact needs to be established about integer starting points to have this apply to them (non-periodic at least).

Comment: One possible problem with your claim is that $/2\pi$ is transcendental and irrational while the ratio is clearly rational, hence they can never be the same.

Comment: @CyeWaldman 
A sequence of all rational terms can converge to a transcendental number. For example, the sequence $a_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}$ [converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3354430/compute-the-sum-of-the-infinite-series-sum-k-0-infty-frac-1k2k1?noredirect=1) to $\pi/4$.

Comment: @Dan Of course, but in this case there is no such summation, it's just a single number that is the ratio of the number of positive outcomes to the total number of trials. I've done this numerically out to &n=10^8&. The results are consistently close to, but less than $1/2\pi$.

Comment: It is very likely that the $\sqrt{2\pi}$ is obtained by sheer coincidence. My calculations for ~1000000 iterations show that the ratio is around 40 percent. This might be easier to explain, since for example the last five elements of the set of 1000000 iterations for $a_1=2$ are $-1.00244, 1.85787, -3.53176, -1.08126, 2.12669$

Comment: My point is, if you take 5 elements of this sequence, there is a good possibility that exactly two of them are positive.

Comment: @polfosol Are you suggesting that the limit is $2/5$ ?

Comment: My computation with $10^8$ terms (using machine precision) shows that the proportion of the positive terms among $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$, with $n$ large enough, is consistently around $0.39885\textsf{x}$, whereas we have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\approx0.398942$. So I guess the limiting proportion, if exists, is different from $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$. It is also interesting that the distribution of the values of $a_n$ is very complicated and fractal-like.

Comment: [Posted on MO.](https://mathoverflow.net/q/456530/494920)